# Hive: Finding average time-difference between rows per group

Tags: hive, hiveql, database-partitioning

I have a table with rows consisting of  in hdfs.
I want to compute the average difference in date for each id for the table.
This is the query I am using , but it keeps giving me error:-

```
select id, AVG(new_visit) over x+1 as avg_lag_btwn_visit
from (select id, date_visit, datediff(date_visit,LAG(date_visit)) over w > 1 as new_visit
      from (select id, date_visit from  table) a
      window w as (partition by id order by date_visit)
     ) b
window x as (partition by id order by date_visit);
```

EDIT:
Sample input:
12345, 2018-01-01
12345, 2018-01-12
23456, 2018-02-01
12345, 2018-01-20
23456, 2018-02-20
34567, 2018-03-01
Sample output:
12345, 9.5
23456, 19
34567, 0

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: Invalid function datediff

Comment: please post the error message, sample input and the expected output as well.

Comment: I have added sameple input and output as well as the error message

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do a DATEDIFF in a window.  You can do SUM/AVG/COUNT/etc.